# Using "random" in Python 2.7.6 to determine gender

Tags: python-2.7, random

I am wondering how I can determine gender using random function in 2.7.6 in a range of (first, last) that counts the number of males with a probability of 30%.

What I know is:

```
def male_in_group(first, last):
   pos = 0
   if: #person is male
      pos = pos + 1
   else: #person is not male
      pos = pos + 0
```

Also, how would I determine the first male in a random group of my range (first, last)?

Comment: How do you determine gender with random? Are you just creating a random data set?

Answer (score 0):

Python's `random.random()` function is what you want. It takes no arguments and produces a random real number between 0 and 1. So the number it produces should be `< .3` approximately 30% of the time. Then you can use this number to decide whether to mark the person as male or not.